# Migrate sync connection settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

How can I Migrate the Synchronization connection settings for User Profile Service Application from SharePoint 2013 to 2016 on premise?

Comment: What u mean connection settings? Are you migrating upa from 2013 to 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into migrating the sync connection setting and I found that It wasn't possible. When you migrate the User Profile Service Application, you can migrate the Profile DB and Social DB. Plus, you need a dedicated MIM Server (FIMs replacement) for 2016.